# How and where is i2c protocol implemented for master send/receive in linux kernel tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, i2c

Apologies for such a generic title but couldn't think of any better.

I am trying to understand where in `drivers/i2c/` is the protocol sequence of sending START, ADDR, DATA, STOP bit sequence implemented, as per the protocol. I want to verify the protocol for send/receive in the driver code, that's all the objective here.

I am using Hikey 620 as a reference which has DesignWare's I2C controller. Below is the registration code I can see ([elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware-master.c#L504)):

```
static const struct i2c_algorithm i2c_dw_algo = {
     .master_xfer = i2c_dw_xfer,
     .functionality = i2c_dw_func,
};
```

If I trace the `i2c_dw_xfer` function recursively, the last call I could see are `readl_relaxed`, `writel_relaxed` in `i2c_dw_xfer_init()` ([elixir](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware-master.c#L188)).

Beyond this is all assembly. Are these `readl`/`writel` the actual sequence of start/data/stop byte sequences? Or am I understanding it totally wrong?

In that case, please help and point me to the correct flow. If what I got is correct, is there some simpler controller code which has a cleaner implementation and can be used as reference.

Comment: It's done in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol itself is not part of the driver code. What the dw_{readl/writel} functions do by calling readl/writel is write to the registers of the I2C peripheral of the concerned SoC. It is the job of the I2C controller on the SoC to then generate the correct I2C signalling. You can see by going through the datasheet that something like DW_IC_CON is a register offset in the I2C peripheral memory map.

Comment: Does that mean the adapter or the client driver need not worry about the start/stop bit sequencing. All they need to do is dump the address and data to be read/written? If yes, can we also assume that the controller firmware is already programmed to follow the i2c protocol and append proper start/stop bits to the message received from adapter drivers?

Comment: No I2C driver worries about start/stop bit sequencing by itself. A driver primarily does two things 1. Setup the registers of the peripheral 2. It integrates with Linux defined I2C core subsystem exposing the I2C device through the /dev/i2c-x interface. There is no such thing as controller firmware in what we are discussing. Any peripheral SoC IP is hardware. "follow the i2c protocol and append proper start/stop bits to the message received from adapter drivers" Yes.

Comment: Thanks but I am still confused here. You mean there is code somewhere in the driver to append start/stop bit sequence or is it done by the controller without any need for the firmware?